# apt-get remove python by accident

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell, ubuntu

Update: Yes it is a stupid move.

As I got some errors in importing some modules/lib (time,select,subprocess). I thought of reinstalling python, a very big mistake. I unfortunately ran `apt-get remove python` and `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python*` 
I have downloaded `Python-2.7.6.tgz` and trying to install. While compiling I am getting an error, after `make install`

```
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmllib.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py ...
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1
```

Is there any way I can restore or install python?
`apt-get -f install` gives out the following error

```
Removing libboost-python1.46-dev ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error processing libboost-python1.46-dev (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libboost-python1.46-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have exported `PYTHONHOME=/usr` but in vain. And this what I get when I run `python` now
`ImportError: No module named site`

Basically I have screwed up python
OS: Ubuntu12.04 LTS - server

UPDATE:

This is error I am getting when I manually install the dependencies

```
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-python-modules", line 13, in <module>
    from subprocess import call
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 427, in <module>
    import select
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/select.so: undefined symbol: _PyInt_AsInt
```

Comment: Try to restore your system. Install Python via `apt-get`. You can also try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without restoring the system

Comment: How about apt-get install --reinstall python?

Comment: The first sentence was not a task, more a headline.

Comment: `apt-get` commands are not working. `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages` is the error I am getting

Comment: I updated my answer. Try that

Comment: your whole OS may have been depending on that python installation. you may have seriously screwed up your whole system.

Comment: Did you figure out your problem?

Comment: finally yes. :) I downloaded all the dependencies, mainly libpython2.7 python2.7-minimal. There were some libs got screwed up

Comment: with `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite` installed one by one. And removed the unmet dependency packages with `sudo dpkg -r`

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed it

- Checked all the dependency packages
- Downloaded the packages one by one matching the version indicated by the previous package with trying to install
- With `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite <pkg>`
  installed the packages ( refer sebenalern's answer to download
  pkgs)
- Removed the unmet dependency packages with `sudo dpkg -r <pkg>`
- Installed
  `python2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb`
  `python2.7-minimal_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb`
  `libpython2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb` at once -> `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
- Was happy that `apt-get` started working again
- Ran `sudo apt-get -f install`
- Ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7`. It got upgraded to 2.7.11
- for all the missing python packages I ran `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
- finally `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 1):

Try using installing a new libboost `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite libboost1.46-all-dev_1.46.1-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb`

You can download it [here.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-all-dev)
and then run:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: I have tried both but it didnt work. It gave the same output `Errors were encountered while processing:
 libboost-python1.46-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: That worked but for rest of the packages I am getting errors I have updated it in the description.

Comment: Now try setting the $PYTHONHOME

Comment: nope :( same error. I am setting PYTHONHOME to /usr